# Disabling Sandbox for NelmioApiDocs on Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, nelmioapidocbundle

i want to disable the sandbox mode for NelmioApiDocs on Symfony "v3.4.11" and nelmio/api-doc-bundle "v3.2.1"

I've tried:

```
# app/config/config.yml

# nelmio_api_doc
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        sandbox:
            enabled: false
```

After that i cleared the cache for prod and dev.
But it did not work, i can still send api tests with "Try it out".

Can someone help me to disable this "Try it out" feature?

Kind Regards,
Benjamin

Comment: Did you found out? I am also looking for this, and I don't really like the idea of disabling it only trough css or javascript....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer from Denis St-Michel was not working for me, i've added css to hide the button:

```
{# create in app\Resources\NelmioApiDocBundle\views\SwaggerUi\index.html.twig #}
{% extends '@!NelmioApiDoc/SwaggerUi/index.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
{#  Eine Config zur Deaktivierung des Buttons hat leider nicht funktioniert, daher einfach ausgeblended  #}
<style>
    .try-out {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

Not the best way, but working for me.

Answer (score 0):

@DasBen, I have the same setup as you, and I was able to disable the sandbox by adding a plugin to the init-swagger-ui.js

```
const DisableTryItOutPlugin = function() {
    return {
        statePlugins: {
            spec: {
                wrapSelectors: {
                    allowTryItOutFor: () => () => false
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then in `const ui` definition I added this plugin like this:

```
plugins: [
    DisableTryItOutPlugin
]
```

Refreshed, and the sandbox is gone. I would have prefered to disabled it via an option in the `config.yml` file under `nelmio_api_doc`, but at least it's disabled now. Hopes this helps.

I shall have no credit, though: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3725#issuecomment-334899276

Comment: After almost a year, i had to do the same. It did not work before and now too. I've hidden the "Try-Out" Button now with css